# Grouping SQL-Result by time does not work

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to set up an SQL query in Firebird 2.5 in order to make a statistic about sales grouped by time.

My approach I followed up so far would be:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS S1, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS S2,
        CASE 
           WHEN (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE)) < 10 THEN 
                '0' || CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ':00 - ' || '0' || 
                CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ':59 ' 
           WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) >= 10 THEN 
                CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ':00 - ' || 
                CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ':59 ' 
        END AS TINTERVAL, 
        COUNT(ODR.ID) AS ABSCOUNT 
FROM ODR 
GROUP BY S1,S2,TINTERVAL
ORDER BY S1,S2 ASC
```

The syntax of this query seems to be fine for SQL-Connection established by Firebird ODBC 2.5.

My question:

For `hour=0 (<10)` the query returns a result set which is not presented by the data given by the orders.

e.g. the result-set for this query might look like this:

1. S1  S2      TINTERVAL       ABSCOUNT
2. 0   0       00:00 - 00:59       30
3. 0   1       01:00 - 01:59        2

I don't know how this query comes to its strange count in hour = 0.
This does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you include what output you got from that query, as well as what the expected output would be and maybe some sample data? Thanks

Comment: ;-) mike, no i can not include hard data. There is probably just a bug with extract(hour from datafield) where datafield = 'dd-mm-yyyy 00:mm:ss'.
I already have validated my query against it and the result does  not correspond to that, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think so. Many people use FB and of them all only you found the obvious bug for which you do not want to show any proof. Chances are small. Where is that bug, show me? `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION'),  extract( hour from cast('10-11-2014 00:30:45' as timestamp) ) from rdb$database` ==> `| 2.5.5 | 0 |` - works as it should

Comment: and frankly, if you wanted to group on an hour of the day, that is what you better do, explicitly adding the column `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ODR.ORDERDATE)` and then grouping by it, rather than grouping by text field

Comment: And finally your string concatenation and uncalled CASE look crazy. There is totally no need for it. `select lpad( extract( hour from cast('10-11-2014 00:30:45' as timestamp) ), 4, 'o') from rdb$database` => `ooo0`

Comment: `select current_timestamp, extract( minute from current_timestamp),
       DATEADD( -extract(minute from current_timestamp) minute to current_timestamp),
       DATEADD( 59-extract(minute from current_timestamp) minute to current_timestamp)
from rdb$database` =>

`| 01.02.2017 17:52 | 52 | 01.02.2017 17:00 | 01.02.2017 17:59 |`

Comment: Arioch: thank you... now it works